# Calling a method in the view controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

To generalize my problem, I am using an API that returns an iterable object. Within that those is an id for each object. My controller looks like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @search = API.find(params[:query])
    end
end
```

My view is something like this:

```
    <% @search.each do |thing| %>
        <h2><%= thing.attr2 if thing.attr1 %></h2>
        <%= API.list(thing.attr2) %>
    <% end %>
```

I have tried adding a method into

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @search = API.find(params[:query])

            def getList(attr2)
                API.list(thing.attr2)
            end   
    end
end
```

and adding index and self before the definition (ex: self.getList(attr2)) and calling it in all those variations in the view:

```
<%= getList(thing.attr2) %>
```

I am wondering where I am going wrong here. I have additionally tried to add in the helper_method line as I read in a few docs but it would not recognize it. Also, would this be the correct way to go about this style-wise? Having a hard time finding references for it makes me think this isn't standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

The method I was trying to make is a helper method, and therefore, needs to go in the helper method for the controller.